# Doorkeeper password grant_type -Token Revocation on password change (with Devise) and Refresh token methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, doorkeeper

I'm currently working with Doorkeeper (+Devise) for a Rails server and trusted iOS app. I've got an implementation working but I am confused on a few things. I have already read the wiki on this: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Interacting-as-an-OAuth-client-with-Doorkeeper

**The current flow:**

1. User logs in with username and password in iOS app. This is sent to https://myserver.com/api/log_in
2. Server checks credentials and logs in user with Devise. Then it responds with the access_token using the `Doorkeeper::AccessToken.find_or_create_for()` method.
3. iOS app saves this token and sends it in `Authorization:Bearer the_access_key` for all future API calls

**So far so good (i.e. the above is working in my test). The questions I have are:**

1. Refresh tokens - should the iOS app check if a refresh is required pro actively (i.e. comparing the `access_token` `created_at` and `expires_in` and then based on the result of this refresh the token), or should it just try to refresh on a 401, and if the refresh also gets a 400/401 then stop and log out user on iOS?
2. Changing password elsewhere and revocation of tokens. If the user changes their password on the website (using Devise), then all iOS app tokens for that user should be revoked. The refresh token should also fail and the user prompted to log in again on iOS app. I haven't found documentation suggesting best practice for this. From my tests this does not happen automatically in Doorkeeper, and the `access_token` is still valid for use. What is the best/correct way to handle this scenario?

Thanks in advance for your time.